# Body 'width' attribute affecting screen calculations

Tags: javascript, css

I've come across an issue with web pages when the BODY has a fixed CSS 'width' applied. It seems that giving a width to the body affects what the browser considers to be pixel 0 when doing screen width calculations/checks (i.e. the left edge of the content rather than the left edge of the browser window).

I have a control which is injected into the page post-load at a specific, calculated position. When the body width is set and the content is narrower than the browser window, the control appears off-screen.

In Chrome and IE10, the "margin-left" and "margin-right" attributes are being dynamically set which means I could still get the right result. However FF & Safari (that I know of) aren't.

Does anyone have any advice or pointers as to how I can accurately get available width information in a reliable, cross-browser compatible way in the scenario of the BODY having an explicit, fixed width? Many thanks...

**UPDATE**: I'm seeing this in particular places, but it appears it's not the "width" attribute causing the issue, it's the presence of a "position: relative" attribute. See jsfiddle link in my comment below.

For clarification, my control is a plug-in which can go onto anyone's site so I need to try to cater for as many potentialities as possible.

Comment: can you plz provide any sample code snippet?

Comment: I can't understand what are you exactly trying to calculate/set and what's your problem... what is that control? some example? http://jsfiddle.net/HEQVb/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/samkirkpatrick/ghGza/ - this is a snapshot of the CSS/set up of a particular site I'm seeing the issue on. Upon further investigation, it's actually the "position" of the body - not the "width" that is causing the problem... main post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements which are set to `position: absolute` will be positioned according to the [content area](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) of their closest `position: relative` ancestor, with `html` being the default if there is no closer `position: relative` ancestor.

If you want your control to always appear 5px down and 300px to the right of the top-left corner of your page, set `html` to `position: relative` and leave body with no `position` set at all.

If you want your control to stick to the top-right of your `body` element, then set `#myblock` to have the following CSS `property: value;` pairs:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghGza/1/)